# icon not clickable with onclick event

Tags: html, onclick, icons

The onclick event only works with the button. If I click on the icon in the button the function does not work.

`enter code here`

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md elementor-animation-grow" id="dropbtn">
```

<i onclick="myFunction() "class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down">

```
<script>/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Try using `element.closest()` instead of `element.matches()`.

I suspect it's the condition in your if statement. By the looks of it, `element.matches()` will match *exactly* the ID provided - I.e., it'll match if the element clicked on has that ID, but not if you click on a child element that does not explicitly have the ID, even if the parent does.

According to [Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), `element.closest()` should also match any elements whose parents match the condition provided, even if the element itself doesn't.

Bear in mind this will change the type of the returned value - `matches()` returns a boolean, while `closest()` returns the 'closest' element matching the condition.